# Where did my VLQ flag option go?

Tags: support, flagging

I was going to flag an answer as VLQ (very low quality) but I can't seem to find it. It also has disappeared from my question flag list as well. No this is not just on one question or on one answer. I have flagged 2 questions as VLQ today, both set as helpful.

[image: VLQ flag missing]

Anybody else with this issue or is it just me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions and answers with a positive net score can't be flagged with VLQ flag. So, a post with a +1 you can downvote it and then cast the flag ;).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah but of course.